# TypeError: The view function for 'create_emp' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, pymysql, flask-apispec

Whenever i run the flask API to inserting the data using postman, but valid response not return response coming,

Method : Post
Postman input : http://127.0.0.1:5000/create

**Body : **

```
{
    "address":"India",
    "email":"abb@gmail.com",
    "name":"kunal p",
    "phone":"8264983779"
}
```

**main code : **

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_emp():
    try:
        _json = request.json
        _name = _json['name']
        _email = _json['email']
        _phone = _json['phone']
        _address = _json['address']
        if _name and _email and _phone and _address and request.method == 'POST':
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO emp(name, email, phone, address) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)"
            bindData = (_name, _email, _phone, _address)
            cursor.execute(sqlQuery, bindData)
            conn.commit()
            respone = jsonify('Employee added successfully!')
            respone.status_code = 200
            return respone
        else:
            return showMessage()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    # finally:
    #     cursor.close()
    #     conn.close()
```

When i run the codes above, this pops up. --> "The view function did not return a valid response. The" TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Comment: ```showMessage()``` is a function. Where did you define it? Does the function have a return statement and does it return something other than ```None```?